# Sending an image using Poco to a webserver

Tags: c++, http, poco-libraries

I'm trying to upload a picture to appengine using POCO::Net::HTMLForm.
Please see the code below. The problem I have is that  the imagedata is not send. The token and the character name (its for an open source action rpg) is transmited without any problem.  Any idea what I may do wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

c++ code:

```
            // prepare session
        Poco::URI uri(backend_url + "/api/update_character_avatar");
        Poco::Net::HTTPClientSession session(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort());

        // prepare path
        std::string path(uri.getPathAndQuery());
        if (path.empty()) path = "/";

        Poco::Net::HTTPRequest req(Poco::Net::HTTPRequest::HTTP_POST, path);
        Poco::Net::HTMLForm form;
        form.add("token", sw_token);
        form.add("charname", sw_charname);

        Poco::Buffer<char> imgBuffer(mImgPtr->size());
        mImgPtr->read(imgBuffer.begin(), imgBuffer.end()-imgBuffer.begin());
        std::string s(imgBuffer.begin(), mImgPtr->size());

        std::ostringstream out;
        Poco::Base64Encoder b64enc(out);
        b64enc.write(imgBuffer.begin(), imgBuffer.end()-imgBuffer.begin());
        b64enc.close();
        Poco::Net::StringPartSource *prtsrc = new Poco::Net::StringPartSource(out.str());
        form.addPart("imagedata", prtsrc);

        form.prepareSubmit(req);
        std::ostream& send = session.sendRequest(req);
        form.write(send);

        // get response
        Poco::Net::HTTPResponse res;

        // print response
        std::istream &is = session.receiveResponse(res);
        std::ostringstream stream;
        Poco::StreamCopier::copyStream(is, stream);
        std::cout << stream.str() << std::endl;
```

Python handler for appengine:

```
class UpdateCharacterAvatarHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def post(self):
    token = self.request.get("token")
    charname = self.request.get("charname")
    imagedata = self.request.get("imagedata")

    logging.error(self.request.body)

    self.response.write("test")
```

Comment: please provide header files of C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I couldn't understand what exactly you are trying to do in this code. There are lot of useless steps you have taken to upload a file as it can be done simply by using HTMLForm class. Here are the minimum code required to do so -

> ```
>     HTTPRequest request(HTTPRequest::HTTP_POST, "/fileupload/upload_file.php",    HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
>     HTMLForm form;
>     form.setEncoding(HTMLForm::ENCODING_MULTIPART);
>     form.addPart("file", new FilePartSource("/home/abc/Pictures/sample.png"));
>     form.prepareSubmit(request);
>
>     HTTPClientSession *httpSession = new HTTPClientSession("localhost");
>     httpSession->setTimeout(Poco::Timespan(20, 0));
>     form.write(httpSession->sendRequest(request));        
>
>     Poco::Net::HTTPResponse res;
>     std::istream &is = httpSession->receiveResponse(res);
>     Poco::StreamCopier::copyStream(is, std::cout);
> ```

The corresponding upload server is using standard PHP code for uploading HTML form files.

Comment: How to use streaming(live camera) images. with this method.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect imagedata to appear as a post field rather than get, so I would try     `imagedata = self.request.post("imagedata")`. Alternatively try posting it to a server which will allow you to set breakpoints and inspect the content of the request.